# Shared storage that doesn't involve installing software for the share

Tags: storage

Is there any storage provider that can allow shared storage without the person allocated shared rights having to install any software?

The reason for this request is that I wish my father who is a little tech limited to be able to share photos etc with me. I wish to do this in the simplest way possible. I envisage him going to a website to upload photos that appear in my shared folder.
E.g. Dropbox allows you to share a folder but the person allocated shared rights must install Dropbox.

Is there a service that will allow this functionality please?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look for sites that offer WebDAV accessible storage. WebDAV client functionality is built in to many operating systems but some implementations are better than others. A quick google search turned up mydisk.se. I have not used them since I normally setup my own WebDAV space when needed so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Basic WebDAV uses http (non-encrypted) and port 80 for communication so when you are researching providers you will want to look for WebDAVs. WebDAVs uses https and provides all the benefits of SSL for security.